# For loop within for loop: pendulum modeling

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested

I am new to programming, and working on a relatively complicated problem. I am modeling a linear forced pendulum, and need to figure out how the amplitude of the swinging motion (in radians) depends on the friction (q-value) and the frequency of the driving force (Omega_D). So, I thought I would need a for-loop inside a for-loop because I need to do plots of Omega_D vs Amplitude for 3 q-values. Thus, iterating 3 times for q, and many more times within that for Omega_D. However, what I wrote is only giving me one amplitude value per q value. Here is my code; let me know what suggestions you may have.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ode import rk4_step


def derivs(t, starting_values):

    d0dt = starting_values[1]
    d20dt2 = g/l * starting_values[0] - starting_values[3] * \
    starting_values[1] + starting_values[4] * np.sin(starting_values[5] * t)

    dqdt = 0.
    dFdt = 0.
    dldt = 0.
    d_Omega_dt = 0.                  # defining these for later use in RK4

    derivatives = np.array([d0dt, d20dt2, dqdt, dFdt, dldt, d_Omega_dt])
    return derivatives



qs = [0.1, 1.0, 1.6] #Pick arbitrary q-values to run through
for i in qs:

    theta_0 = 10.    #initial values, chosen at random
    theta_v0 = 10.
    l = 1. 
    Omega_D = np.linspace(0.5, 5, 100)
    F_D = .3
    for x in Omega_D:
        starting_values = [theta_0, theta_v0, l, i, F_D, x] 
        solution = np.copy(starting_values)
        last_values = np.zeros(solution.size)

    dt = .01
    g = -9.8   

    t = 0.
    Amp = 0.


    starttime = 150.

    while Amp == 0. :  #Amp==0 because it never actually WILL be zero.
               #So, the while loop to find amplitude only needs to run \
               #until a nonzero amp is found
        two_values_ago = np.copy(last_values)
        last_values = np.copy(solution)


        t = t + dt
        solution = rk4_step(solution, derivs, t, dt)  #take a step


         if solution[1] == 0 and t > starttime:  #if somehow we hit v=0 exactly
            Amp == np.abs(solution[0])
            print Amp

#This if statement interpolates to find the amp at the point where v=0
        if solution[1] * last_values[1] < 0 and t > starttime:
            fit_vs = np.array([two_values_ago[1], last_values[1]])
            fit_xs = np.array([two_values_ago[0], last_values[0]])
            v_interp = 0.
            Amp = np.abs(np.interp(v_interp, fit_vs, fit_xs))


    w = np.sqrt(-g / l) # This is the natural frequency

#Calculate the analytic soln
    exact_solution = F_D / np.sqrt((w**2 - Omega_D**2)**2 + (i * Omega_D)**2)

#plot num and exact solns together
    plt.plot(Omega_D, exact_solution)
    plt.plot(Omega_D, Amp)
    plt.title('q = ')
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude (radians)')
    plt.xlabel('$\Omega_{D}$ (rad/s)')

    print Amp 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with indentation.  This portion of the code is being run as part of the "outer" for loop, which means it is run for only the last value of "Amp" that is left when the inner "for" loop finishes:

```
    w = np.sqrt(-g / l) # This is the natural frequency

#Calculate the analytic soln
    exact_solution = F_D / np.sqrt((w**2 - Omega_D**2)**2 + (i * Omega_D)**2)

#plot num and exact solns together
    plt.plot(Omega_D, exact_solution)
    plt.plot(Omega_D, Amp)
    plt.title('q = ')
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude (radians)')
    plt.xlabel('$\Omega_{D}$ (rad/s)')

    print Amp
```

You need to indent one level more so it is run as part of the inner "for" loop.

Also, this line is not doing what you want:

```
        Amp == np.abs(solution[0])
```

You are trying to assign np.abs(solution[0]) to Amp, but instead you are testing if np.abs(solution[0]) is equal to Amp (but then tossing away the result of the test).  This line should be:

```
        Amp = np.abs(solution[0])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was a great explanation for someone who is just beginning programming. I appreciate it.